# Sum of elements in text file using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Using pyspark, I can find the count value of the data in the text file. But what I want is that I want to sum up the numbers in the text file. How can he do it. Part of the text file looks like this:

1.3515 
1.3475 
1.3375 
1.3345 
1.3315 
1.3315

My Code :

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="RangeOfDoviz")
RDD = sc.textFile("/home/andropat/PycharmProjects/sparking/ranges.txt")
```

[RESOLVED]

Comment: You can do this pretty easily in vanilla python... is pyspark necessary?

Comment: I need to do it using PySpark

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say `RDD.sum()`

Comment: Error Message  : return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'

Comment: try `RDD.map(float).sum()`

Comment: Thank u so much!!! I'm having difficulty learning new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spark `DataFrames`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark.read \
    .schema(StructType([StructField("value", DoubleType())])) \
    .text(path) \
    .groupBy().sum() \
    .first()[0]
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum

spark.read \
    .text(path) \
    .groupBy().agg(sum(col("value").cast("double"))) \
    .first()[0]
```

It requires more code but should be faster than using RDD.